# IntelliJ IDEA invalid breakpoint

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I have installed IntelliJ IDEA and upgraded a web project to run with Tomcat. It works fine but after some time I have discovered that I'm not able to debug some code I add to the end of class. Because when I set a breakpoint in this code it marks as invalid. If I hover the invalid mark the warning message appears `Warning: No executable code found at line xxx in class yyy`.

The screenshot of the source code in editor when web application is running in debug mode:

[image]

Does anybody know why IntelliJ Idea can't find executable code there and how to set a valid breakpoint like the first one in the code that compiles and running?

Comment: Are you doing remote debug over Tomcat ? If so, make sure that the source you're looking it is the same as the compiled classes deployed to Tomcat. This is usually what's causing the issue.

Comment: @eitanfar Seems you were right, but how could such happen if the classes deployed to Tomcat were up to date?

Comment: Well, it just happens sometimes, mostly due to file timestamp issues and such. I'm using ANT to deploy a budled war of all my classes at once using Catalina ANT tasks, and doing so avoids those problems completely. Of course, it's slower that way.

Comment: @eitanfar Don't you know that Idea doesn't deploy to the Tomcat running locally, it's just use `docBase` in external configuration.

Comment: It doesn't matter. At the end you're going to use one build system or another, and not rely on IntelliJ, so why not start now ?

Comment: @eitanfar No, I can't avoid IntelliJ because it's a key in this question. And the build system for those who build it but IntelliJ for those who develop it. Find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

When I have this problem, I go to menu "File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart". The problem is likely that the IntelliJ cache isn't up to date yet.